# Disable --noprofile in Firejail

Tags: firejail

How can I disable the `--noprofile` option in Firejail? For example, is it possible to disable the use of this option in `firejail.config` so that no one can use it.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: As in, use of firejail is not mandatory, right (unless you run the whole user login session through it)? So, can't any user simply elect not to run their program with firejail anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Firejail does contain a way to restrict user sessions, but it probably is too coarse for what you want to do.

Open file `/etc/firejail/login.users` and specify sandbox options for each user, for example:

```
username: --noprofile --private-tmp --private-dev --caps.drop=all --seccomp=!chroot
```

Then change the user shell to `/usr/bin/firejail` in `/etc/passwd`. This way the entire user session runs in one and the same Firejail sandbox. Note that you usually won't be able to run sudo and friends in that session, so be careful to not lock yourself out.

For original documentation see [man firejail-login](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/login.users.5.html).

If a one-size-fits-all sandbox is not what you need, better check out proper Mandatory Access Control (MAC) systems like AppArmor, SELinux or Tomoyo.